# Не работает ajax запрос на передачу переменной из JS в PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Сделал ajax запрос на передачу переменной с js файла в php файл

js:

```
    var scores = 10;
var send = function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dobavl.php",
        data: { score: scores },
        success: function(data){
      console.log("success", data);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      console.log("ERROR", xhr);
    }
    });
};
```

PHP:

```
$sname = "Кислюк";
$fname = "Влад";
$score = $_POST['score'];
if ($_POST['score'] != 0 );

$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
if (false === $link)
   die ('Error database connect');
$select_result = mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
if (false === $select_result)
   die ('Error database select<');
$query = "INSERT INTO records VALUES('$sname','$fname','$score')";
$query_result = mysql_query($query, $link);
if (false === $query_result)
   die ('Error database SQL query');
$close_result = mysql_close($link);
if (false === $close_result)
   die ('Error database close');
   ?>
```

Но после выполнения 0 реакции, не переменная не передаётся, не ошибка не вылезла. Просто молчание, хотя по сути должен выдаться:

Alert: Данные успешно получены!

Comment: `if ($_POST['score']=='35')`, `console.log(data);` -?

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. А как передать не заданное число а переменную. Как это написать в data?

Comment: добавил в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var scores = 10;

var send = function(){
  console.log("called send");

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dobavl.php",
    data: { 
      score: scores,
      key2: value2,
      key3: value3 
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log("success", data);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      console.log("ERROR", xhr);
    }  
  });
};
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77929/discussion-on-answer-by-igor---ajax------j).